# Connecting points to the nearest K polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, closest-distance

I have a layer of point data, and a layer that contains polygons of all the lakes in a region. I am trying to find the K closest of these lakes for each point. The distance should be measured from the point to the closest edge of each lake.

All solutions I have seen so far either can only connect a point to the centroid of the lake polygon, and can only make the closest connection (whereas I am trying to make K connections from each point to the closest lake polygons).

The tools I have tried to far:

- "Join by lines (hub lines)" - this can only connect each point with its nearest single lake
- GRASS v.distance tool - can only connect each point to 1 polygon

Below is an image of what I am trying to achieve (shown for a single point and for k=3).

[image: Example of what I would like to achieve, where k=3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy with [Shortest line between features](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisshortestline).

Points should be Input layer, and polygons Destination layer. Maximum number of neighbors=3.

THe output will be a line layer connecting each point the the closest three polygons. The line will have all point and polygon attributes from the two connected features, and a distance:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the nearest points go to `Processing`, search for `Nearest`, then `Join attributes by nearest`. You can then input your two vector layers and specify the max nearest neighbours to 3.